# Adding data dynamically in flexigrid

Tags: jquery, rows, dynamically-generated, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid and data is added dynamically to that grid. But for some reason, the rows aren't properly formatted (css style wise). I have tried calling `jQuery('#tblEntAttributes').flexigrid();` after dynamically populating the table, where tblEntAttributes is my table name. But the rows still appear disoriented. By table rows contain normal text along with some checkboxes.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: It cannot be a formatted json data, because the rows contain checkboxes along with text. When I statically put in the checkboxes and data in a table and call `jQuery('#tblEntAttributes').flexigrid(); ` on document on ready, the table gets formatted properly. So why isn't `jQuery('#tblEntAttributes').flexigrid(); ` doing the same thing when called explicitly?

Comment: How are you adding those additional rows, ajax?

Comment: Dynamically like `jQuery('#tblEntAttributes tbody').append(newRowContent); ` where `newRowContent` contains a HTML markup string consisting of TD, TR and other elements.